The beampattern of a uniform linear array on the z axis

I understand that the beampattern of a uniform linear array is as follows viewing from the x-y plane. But what does it look like on the z-axis?
Is the beampattern the same from all cross-sections on the z-axis?

If it is a linear array with elements placed along the y-axis, and IF all the elements themselves are omni-directional then you can simply rotate this pattern about the y-axis.
This should be intuitive by considering the graphic below showing the propagation from 2 antenna elements positioned along the y-axis. Shown on the left is the propagation from each of those elements along the x-axis, and the resulting pattern is based on how those waves would combine in any direction in the x-y plane. Assuming the elements are omni-directional, then if we were to rotate the x-y plane around the y-axis (to reveal the z-axis as shown on the right), then we see how the propagation along the z-axis in the x-z plane should be identical to that in the x-y plane: Since the antenna is omnidirectional, then we can rotate any antenna element without a change to the resulting pattern as long as the relative positions of each element to each other do not change. Thus the resulting pattern will be invariant to a rotation along y.

The assumption that the elements are omni-directional is not a good one in practice as there is no such antenna element. However this model is useful as it forms the base pattern from which we can derive the actual pattern. The actual 3D pattern would be this base pattern derived from the omni-directional element assumption, together with the pattern of the individual elements as an overall envelope. For this reason, to really know what the pattern would be along the z-axis, we need to know the element pattern itself.
